# Delete files by Specifying directory

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am using the following batch script while deletes files below a certain size.

```
@echo off
setlocal
:: Size is in bytes
set "min.size=100000"

for /f  "usebackq delims=;" %%A in (`dir /b /A:-D *.*`) do If %%~zA LSS %min.size% del "%%A"
```

This works if I put the batch file inside the folder but it deletes the batch file also.

However how do I keep the batch file at a different position and specify the directory path explicitly?

Comment: You could filter out the batch file, `%0`, using `If`, `Find` or `FindStr`, leaving it in the same folder!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest solution is making the directory on which to delete files like `C:\Temp\Test` temporarily the active directory.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
rem Size is in bytes
set "min.size=100000"
set "FullBatchFileName=%~f0"

pushd "C:\Temp\Test"
rem Do nothing if the command line above fails unexpected.
if errorlevel 1 goto EndBatch

for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir * /A-D-H /B /OS 2^>nul') do if not "%FullBatchFileName%" == "%%~fI" if %%~zI LSS %min.size% ( del "%%I" ) else goto DeletionDone

:DeletionDone
popd

:EndBatch
endlocal
```

The **DIR** command line is executed by **FOR** in a separate command process started with `cmd.exe /C` in background and **FOR** captures all lines output by **DIR** to handle **STDOUT**. An error message output by **DIR** to handle **STDERR** on finding not any non-hidden file in current directory is redirected with `2>nul` to device **NUL** to suppress it.

Read also the Microsoft article about [Using Command Redirection Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) for an explanation of `2>nul`. The redirection operator `>` must be escaped with caret character `^` on **FOR** command line to be interpreted as literal character when Windows command interpreter processes this command line before executing command **FOR** which executes the embedded `dir` command line with using a separate command process started in background.

The **DIR** option `/OS` results in getting the list of non-hidden files output by **DIR** ordered by size with smallest first and largest last.

**FOR** would skip lines starting with a semicolon which means it would skip files which file name starts with `;` which is in general possible. This is avoided by specifying with `eol=|` the vertical bar as end of line character which no file name can contain.

**FOR** would split up the lines into substring using normal space and horizontal tab as delimiter and would assign only first substring to loop variable `I`. File names can contain one or more spaces. Therefore `delims=` is used to define an empty list of delimiters which disable the line splitting behavior completely and get assigned to loop variable `I` the entire file name.

The **IF** condition `if not "%FullBatchFileName%" == "%%~fI"` compares case-sensitive the full qualified name of the batch file (drive + path + name + extension) with full qualified name of current file. This condition is only **true** if the current file is not the currently running batch file.

The next **IF** condition `if %%~zI LSS %min.size%` compares the file size of current file converted to a 32-bit signed integer with the specified file size also converted to a 32-bit signed integer. This file size comparison fails on files with 2 [GiB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibibyte) or more as such a large file exceeds the maximum positive 32-bit signed integer value 2147483647.

The **FOR** loop is exited with `goto DeletionDone` on first line having a file size equal or greater the specified minimum size because of all further files output by **DIR** have definitely a file size equal or greater than the specified minimum size because of being output ordered by size from smallest to largest.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `call /?` ... explains `%~f0` ... full qualified file name of argument 0 - the currently executed batch file.
- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `popd /?`
- `pushd /?`
- `rem /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to push ahead into PowerShell, the following script might work. When you are confident that the correct files will be deleted, remove the `-WhatIf` from the `Remove-Item` cmdlet.

```
$deldir = 'C:\Temp'
$minsize = 100000
$precious = 'Remove-UnderSize.ps1', 'Remove-UnderSize.bat'

Get-ChildItem -File -Path $deldir |
    ForEach-Object {
        if (-not ($precious -contains $_.Name)) {
            if ($_.Length -lt $minsize) {
                Remove-Item -Path $_.FullName -WhatIf
            }
        }
    }
```

This script can be called from a cmd.exe bat file script.

```
powershell -NoProfile -File .\Remove-UnderSize.ps1
```